# Programmaitcally adding nature to existing project

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

When i adjust the project nature of a running project

```
WorkspaceJob job = new WorkspaceJob("AddingNature") {

        @Override
        public IStatus runInWorkspace(IProgressMonitor monitor)
                throws CoreException {
try {

       IProjectDescription description = activeProject
                        .getDescription();
       String[] prevNatures = description.getNatureIds();
       String[] newNatures = new String[prevNatures.length + 1];
       System.arraycopy(prevNatures, 0, newNatures, 0,
            prevNatures.length);
       newNatures[prevNatures.length] = ID;

       description.setNatureIds(newNatures);
       activeProject.setDescription(description,
          new NullProgressMonitor());
       return Status.OK_STATUS;
   } catch (CoreException e) {
       LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, WARNING_NATURE_FAIL, e.getMessage());          
       return Status.CANCEL_STATUS;
    }  
}
job.schedule()
```

I get an error 
" The resource tree is locked for modifications."
An exception stack trace is not available.

I thought the schuduling should avoid the resource tree from being locked.
What can i do to prevent this?, is there an other way to add natures / convert projects

*This code is called from a menuitem using a class that extends AbstractHandler.*

Comment: Possibly caused by using a WorkspaceJob, I don't see anything else doing this. Most things use IRunnableWithProgress.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with size of array `String[] newNatures`.

Try this:

```
public static void addProjectNature(IProject project, String natureID, boolean addFirst) {
    try {
        IProjectDescription description = project.getDescription();
        if (description.hasNature(natureID)) {
            return;
        }
        String[] natures = description.getNatureIds();
        String[] newNatures = new String[natures.length + 1];

        if (addFirst) {
            System.arraycopy(natures, 0, newNatures, 1, natures.length);
            newNatures[0] = natureID;
        } else {
            System.arraycopy(natures, 0, newNatures, 0, natures.length);
            newNatures[natures.length] = natureID;
        }
        IStatus status = project.getWorkspace().validateNatureSet(newNatures);
        if (status.getCode() == IStatus.OK) {
            description.setNatureIds(newNatures);
            project.setDescription(description, null);
        } else {
            //Error message
        }
    } catch (CoreException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, that is well spotted. However i pasted the code when i was trying some stuf out, the "new String[natures.length + 1];" was in my code. I edited my code in the original post. btw if i put prevnatures back in the discription there is no error

Comment: Check the .log file for any errors in .metadata folder and update the post. Also the new nature ID is valid one? Open the .project file in an external text editor and run the code to check whether external editor prompt you to reload the content.